# Way to know no of edited post

Tags: discussion, specific-question

How can I know that how many of post user have edited. As user can check most of the activity listed here https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=general&filter=gold, but I couldn't found a way to get no of edited post.

Is there a way about which I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Go to [your profile -> Activity -> Revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/656600/rptwsthi?tab=activity&sort=revisions).

You can also find the number of your edits [in the review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats) via badge progress.

> [image]